# T-SQL SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT for repeating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to return only the first row of each repeating number apart from zeros in the query :

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 

(
ID NVARCHAR(10)
,Number INT

)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG47',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('AG9',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('BF27',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('F98',0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('GC5',0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('KL81',0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('WR52',0)

 SELECT * FROM @Test
```

I'm trying to get :

ID   Number

```
TG32    6
BF27    2
F98     0
GC5     0
HT76    0
KL81    0
WR52    0
```

Comment: I've tried DISTINCT, NULLIF, CASE Statements to no avail :-(

Comment: you say "return ONLY the first row of each repeating number"... in order to achieve that it has to be tracked by an additional column that has either a timestamp or a  serially incrementing id using identity column or a sequence or guid etc .... otherwise SQL Server does not guarantee to return rows in the order that they were inserted.

Comment: Ok, first of all, your example does not have any columns with repeating numbers. If you wish for anyone to get the result you want, give them the ability to produce the correct results.

Comment: There is no first row.  Table has no inherent order.

Comment: Columns 1-5 have repeating numbers 6,6,6,2,2,both methods below return the desired results.

Comment: Show does not mean it will show desired / same results every time.  Min will show AG9.   I am just trying to help you.  Table has no inherent order.  The accepted answer is nondeterministic.  And that would be rows not columns.  They don't return the posted desired results in your question.

Comment: I apologise I should have spent more time putting together the temp table, the Number column is meant to represent a customerID and the ID is meant to represent a product, zeros are customers with only one product  and any number greater than zero is a customer who has many products. The actual product doesn't matter just that I only list each customer once in the result, sorry for not being more specific with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this using ROW_NUMBER and sub query.

```
SELECT ID, Number
FROM (
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY (SELECT 1))as RN
    FROM @test) as d
WHERE (CASE WHEN d.Number = 0 THEN 1 ELSE d.RN END) = 1
```

Also you can use another WHERE statement

```
WHERE d.Number = 0 OR d.RN = 1
```

With CTE:

```
 ;WITH cte as (
 SELECT  *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY (SELECT 1))as RN
 FROM @test)

 SELECT ID, Number
 FROM cte
 WHERE Number = 0 or RN = 1
```

Comment: SELECT ID, Number
        FROM (
            SELECT  *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY        Number                           ORDER    BY (SELECT 1))as RN
            FROM @test) as d
        WHERE (CASE WHEN d.Number  = 0 THEN 1 ELSE d.RN END) = 1

Comment: Where case is over complicated.  d.Number = 0 or d.RN = 1

Comment: @Paparazzi maybe a little bit complicated. Add this to my answer.

Comment: Actually there is no guarantee this will get the first row.   In that simple example rows tend to come out in the order they went in but that is not a guarantee.

Comment: @Justin add query sample with cte.

Comment: @Paparazzi thank you for your valuable reply. There is no guarantee indeed and there is a comment to this question advising to use some identity or timestamp column. (SELECT 1) in ROW_NUMBER() just order this rows as there were inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ID column is ordered you can group on number and get the minimum of `ID` but rule out the rows with number = 0 and then union the rows where number is 0. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508230) implements that:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as ID -- get the minimum value in a group
     , number        -- the nmber for the group
FROM @test
WHERE number <> 0    -- but leave out rows where number is zero
GROUP BY number      -- get those together
UNION                -- add all the other rows
SELECT id
     , number
FROM @test
WHERE number = 0     -- that have a number that is zero
```

Which results in:

```
BF27 2
AG9  6
F98  0
GC5  0
HT76 0
KL81 0
WR52 0
```

Comment: This does not show first row.   There actually is no first row.  At least this would have repeatable results.   No guarantee the accepted answer would have repeatable results.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Test
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of breaking it into a #Table with a clause then applying another clause to the #Temp table?